# video not converted to flv, but reduced in size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video, jwplayer

I am applying this change to every video to convert it into `.flv` file-

```
public void TestConverter(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0 && file != null)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/" + file.FileName);
                string outputpath = Server.MapPath("~/Videos-Original/");
                file.SaveAs(path);

                FFMpegConverter ff = new FFMpegConverter();
                ff.ConvertMedia(Server.MapPath("~/Videos/" + file.FileName), (outputpath + file.FileName), Format.flv);
}
}
```

**Note-**

I am uploading file named `Wildlife.wmv` of size `25MB`.
After passing video through this code my video is converted to `6MB` in size and Extension is still same as it was `Wildlife.wmv`

How Do I convert it to `.flv` file so that My player supports this.

**Player I am using JWPlayer-**

where path in this case- `/Videos-Original/Wildlife.wmv`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('player').setup({
            file: '@Model.videopath',
            title: '@Model.videoname',
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                primary: 'flash'
            });
    </script>
```

How Do I convert any extension to `.flv` so that JWplayer supports it?

Library I am using here is- http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx

Comment: Why not use FFMPEG and encode to MP4 instead of FLV?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer,Because i didn't find some easily understandable examples over this conversion.

Comment: There are some I found looking online - http://bit.ly/1fQNOaF

Comment: Ethan is right - why not convert to MP4, which is virtually universal, instead of FLV, which is a dying format, completely unusable on any mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

Hope following link can help you....

> http://ranawd.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/convert-viedo-to-flv-using-c-net-on-web/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only problem in your case is resulting file extension (it remains ".wmv") but actually it contains FLV media data.

Just change output file extension, something like that:

```
ff.ConvertMedia(Server.MapPath("~/Videos/" + file.FileName), 
    (outputpath +  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( file.FileName )+".flv" ), Format.flv);
```